Best approach to swapping content in a page
What is the correct approach for swapping the entire content of the page? Lets say you have a media center and when the user selects a movie you want the entire page to show a MediaPlayerElement which is the movie playing filled on the entire page. Isn't there any guidelines for doing this in WinUi/WindowsAppSdk?
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3Demo.Pages.MediaCenterPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3Demo.Pages"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:WinUI3Demo.ViewModels"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <models:MediaModel x:Name="Model" />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Padding="16">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTextBlock" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="0,15,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Stretch="UniformToFill">
                <MediaPlayerElement
                    x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                    AreTransportControlsEnabled="False"
                    AutoPlay="True" />
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="ContentTextBlock"
                    Width="880"
                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="250"
            Padding="0,10,0,0"
            ContentOrientation="Horizontal">
            <ItemsView
                x:Name="MediaCenterItemView"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind Model.Objects, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectionChanged="ItemsView_SelectionChanged">
                <ItemsView.Layout>
                    <LinedFlowLayout
                        ItemsStretch="Fill"
                        LineHeight="250"
                        MinItemSpacing="15" />
                </ItemsView.Layout>
                <ItemsView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MediaObject">
                        <ItemContainer>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{x:Bind Thumbnail, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ItemContainer>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsView.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsView>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</Page>


Also, as Frame Class states, You use the Frame control to support navigation to Page instances. You create as many different page types as needed to present the content in your app, and then navigate to those pages by calling the Navigate method and passing in the type of the page to navigate to. You can also pass in a parameter object to initialize the page to a particular state.

Instead of swapping the content of the page, I would recommend using multiple pages and navigate between them.

You can use a Frame for navigation:
SomePage.xaml
<Page...>
    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
</Page>

SomePage.xaml.cs
// You can use navigation.
ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage));

// Or you can set the Frame's Content.
ContentFrame.Content = new AnotherPage();

